# Amazon - Can't request performance report using Advertising API

Tags: amazon-advertising-api

I'm getting an error using amazon advertising API. I'm currently trying to request performance report using `https://advertising-api.amazon.com/v1/campaigns/report`.
But the server reply `Cannot consume content type`

here is my request header and body.

End point : `https://advertising-api.amazon.com/v1/campaigns/report`

Method Type: `POST`

Header :

```
{
     Authorization: 'Bearer xxxxxx',
     Amazon-Advertising-API-Scope: '11111111111',
     Content-Type: 'application/json'
}
```

Body :

```
{
    campaignType:'sponsoredProducts',
    reportDate:'20180320',
    metrics:'impressions,clicks'
}
```

I think I did everything correctly as API document but it says

`{
    "code": "415",
    "details": "Cannot consume content type"
}`

Please help me.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code with which you are calling the API. I think your JSON body is not in correct format, should be double quotes.

Comment: Hi @SandeepRandhawa,  I used Postman for testing. so actually there is no any quotes.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of Postman omitting your credentials of course.

Comment: I have just updated the post.

Comment: you are sending it as a form data. You should choose raw and type as JSON. Then format the JSON body properly with value in double qoutes.

Comment: Thank you. You saved me. now I'm getting correct download URL from response but how can I download that? when I request that url, it also say like above.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
curl -X POST \
  https://advertising-api.amazon.com/v1/campaigns/report \
  -H 'Amazon-Advertising-API-Scope: REPLACE_YOUR_PROFILE_ID' \
  -H 'Authorization: REPLACE_YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Host: advertising-api.amazon.com' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d '{
      "campaignType": "sponsoredProducts",
      "metrics": "impressions,clicks",
      "reportDate": "20181101"
    }
```

And you will get a response like

```
{
  "reportId": "amzn1.clicksAPI.v1.p1.......",
  "recordType": "campaign",
  "status": "IN_PROGRESS",
  "statusDetails": "Report is being generated."
}
```

You can put this curl command in Postman also.

Answer (score 1):

I think your Body may be missing a parameter. When I successfully make a similar POST I need my body to have at least what you have written as well as the segment type. Try adding this to your body:

```
{
campaignType:'sponsoredProducts',
reportDate:'20180320',
metrics:'impressions,clicks'
segment:'query'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the body from the documentation and paste it in the raw area (of postman) and choose JSON format. For me it works fine.